# How to do Regular Expressions in JavaScript, Python, and SQL with multiple brackets and generate string from brackets that contains specific character

Tags: javascript, python, regex, mysql-regexp

So, I have this data

```
{"ABC":"Hello"},{"DEF":"World"},{"GHI":"!!!"}
```

---

How to make a regex to generate a string inside brackets that contains `ABC` so it will return `Hello`?

I also want to generate a string inside brackets that contains `GHI` so it will return `!!!`

I will be using this in JavaScript, Python, and REGEXP_EXTRACT function in SQL.

---

Currently I am trying to do this

```
{"DEF":"(.*?)"}
```

But the result is

```
{"ABC":"Hello"},World,{"GHI":"!!!"}
```

---

I got the solution

I should add `.*` in before and after my regex

so

```
.*{"ABC":"(.*?)"}.*
```

will result `Hello`

Comment: In which programming language or regexp library? Why specifically regular expressions? Can the string contain escapes like `\"`?

Comment: @Arkku, I am using this in JavaScript, Python, and REGEXP_EXTRACT function in SQL, basically needs 3 of them

Comment: Ok, I suggest editing the question to contain this information, and preferably also your attempts at doing it.

Comment: @Arkku, my bad, I add the question and my attempts, already got the the answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Made an [example](https://regex101.com/r/7SgJhq/1/) on your line. Something like this looks like a regular: `.*({\"ABC\":\".*?\"}).*`
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtyEp.png)

Comment: Hei, thanks!!


I modified your regex into `.*{"DEF":"(.*?)"}.*` and result `World`

Comment: OK. I'm glad I helped. At first there was no explanation. I thought you needed the whole thing in {...}.